# Check if two Arraylist entries have same field and sum them

Tags: java

I know the title might be a little confuzing, but I'll detail it now...
I have an object called Dispatch and this is its code

```
public class Dispatch {
    private string DispatchName;
    private double Weight;
    ...
```

My user will be choosing multiple Dispatches and input their weight, after clicking button that list will be sent to server, but at the same time, I want to save the same list to another list who we will call copyList.

But before adding to copyList, I want to check if there is already an item inside copyList who has the exact same name (`DispatchName`) as the one who I'm adding. If it has, then just add the weight from the one I'm adding to the weight on the list. And if there is not an item with the same name it should add the whole item.

Note: **I can't use Java 8**, since I am limited to Android API  19. I know that it's possible with `stream`, but I need other solution.

I tryed with double `foreach` but just can't get the solution.

Comment: Does it have to be a List?  Can you use a Map with name as the key?  If it must be a List, do you have an `Dispatch.equals()` method based on the name?  If yes, use `List.indexOf()` to find a match.

Comment: It can be Map, and no, I dont have `equals()` method.

Comment: Can you write an equals() method? If not, what about a Property Comparator? https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanComparator.html

Comment: @SaxyPandaBear I can owerride equals() method to comapre names of two Dispatches.

Comment: Ideally, you would have a `Map<String, List<Dispatch>>`

Comment: And if there are two items which have the exact name ?

Comment: OP already defined that 2 items of the same name adds to the weight as opposed to adding the item to the list.

Answer (score 0):

You mean

```
HashMap<String,Double> copyListHehe=new HashMap<>();
Dispatch thingy;
...
if(copyListHehe.containsKey(thingy.DispatchName))
  copyListHehe.put(thingy.DispatchName,copyListHehe.get(thingy.DispatchName)+thingy.Weight);
else
  copyListHehe.put(thingy.DispatchName,thingy.Weight);
```

?
("Hehe" because it is not a List, but a Map)

Comment: I interpret "I'm adding to the weight on the list" as mathematical addition here. If you need to know the individual dispatches for a category at the end, then comes the "List in a Map" approach suggested by @cricket_007 in the comments (not here, but in the question)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments try to implement `Dispatch.equals` as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    boolean ret = false;
    if (this == o) {
        ret = true;
    } else if (o != null) && (getClass() == o.getClass()) {
        Dispatch d = (Dispatch)o;
        ret = Object.equals(DispatchName, d.DispatchName)
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Better also change your code to rely on a `Set` (like `HashSet<DispatchName>`) and use `Set.contains()` like:

```
DispatchName d = ...
if(hs.contains(d)) {
   DispatchName d2 = hs.get(d);
   hs.add(new DispatchName(d.DispatchName, d.Weight + d2.Weight);
} else {
   hs.add(d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach to do this its a Set data structure which will permit you to manage duplicates value without workarounds .

Lets see the both approach with a list and with Set:

**With List :**

```
import java.util.List;

public class Dispatcher implements Comparable<Dispatcher>{

    private String DispatchName;
    private double Weight;

    public String getDispatchName() {
        return DispatchName;
    }
    public void setDispatchName(String dispatchName) {
        DispatchName = dispatchName;
    }
    public double getWeight() {
        return Weight;
    }
    public void setWeight(double weight) {
        Weight = weight;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Dispatcher o) {

        if(this.getDispatchName().equals(o.getDispatchName()))
        return 0;
        return -1;
    }

    public static void compareDispatcher(List<Dispatcher> l , Dispatcher d){

        for(Dispatcher item : l){
            if(item.compareTo(d)==0)
                item.setWeight(item.getWeight()+d.getWeight());
        }
    }

}
```

> Note that the same logic of compareDispatcher should be used even for each insert in list to guarrantee unique logic objects .

**main example**

```
Dispatcher d1 = new Dispatcher();
        d1.setDispatchName("A");
        d1.setWeight(3L);

        Dispatcher d2 = new Dispatcher();
        d2.setDispatchName("B");
        d2.setWeight(1L);

        List<Dispatcher> l = new ArrayList<Dispatcher>();

        l.add(d1);
        l.add(d2);


        for(Dispatcher d : l){
            System.out.println(d.getDispatchName());
            System.out.println(d.getWeight());
            System.out.println("*************************");
        }

        System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++");

        Dispatcher d3 = new Dispatcher();
        d3.setDispatchName("A");
        d3.setWeight(2L);

        Dispatcher.compareDispatcher(l, d3);

        for(Dispatcher d : l){
            System.out.println(d.getDispatchName());
            System.out.println(d.getWeight());
            System.out.println("*************************");
        }

        System.out.println("end");
```

**With Set :**

This is the best way beacuse implementing hashcode and equals you guarrantee unique objects in your data structure.

```
import java.util.Set;

public class Dispatcher implements Comparable<Dispatcher>{

    private String DispatchName;
    private double Weight;

    public String getDispatchName() {
        return DispatchName;
    }
    public void setDispatchName(String dispatchName) {
        DispatchName = dispatchName;
    }
    public double getWeight() {
        return Weight;
    }
    public void setWeight(double weight) {
        Weight = weight;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((DispatchName == null) ? 0 : DispatchName.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Dispatcher other = (Dispatcher) obj;
        if (DispatchName == null) {
            if (other.DispatchName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!DispatchName.equals(other.DispatchName))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Dispatcher o) {

        if(this.getDispatchName().equals(o.getDispatchName()))
        return 0;
        return -1;
    }

    public static void compareDispatcher(Set<Dispatcher> l , Dispatcher d){

        for(Dispatcher item : l){
            if(item.compareTo(d)==0)
                item.setWeight(item.getWeight()+d.getWeight());
        }
    }

}
```

**main example**

```
Dispatcher d1 = new Dispatcher();
        d1.setDispatchName("A");
        d1.setWeight(3L);

        Dispatcher d2 = new Dispatcher();
        d2.setDispatchName("B");
        d2.setWeight(1L);

        Dispatcher d4 = new Dispatcher();
        d4.setDispatchName("A");
        d4.setWeight(2L);

        Set<Dispatcher> l = new HashSet<Dispatcher>();

        l.add(d1);
        l.add(d2);
        l.add(d4);

        for(Dispatcher d : l){
            System.out.println(d.getDispatchName());
            System.out.println(d.getWeight());
            System.out.println("*************************");
        }

        System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++");

        Dispatcher d3 = new Dispatcher();
        d3.setDispatchName("A");
        d3.setWeight(2L);

        Dispatcher.compareDispatcher(l, d3);

        for(Dispatcher d : l){
            System.out.println(d.getDispatchName());
            System.out.println(d.getWeight());
            System.out.println("*************************");
        }

        System.out.println("end");
```

> Didn't add duplicate object :

```
Dispatcher d4 = new Dispatcher();
  d4.setDispatchName("A");
  d4.setWeight(2L);
```

Comment: If the list is empty, it will not add new item.
This only works if there are items in the list, but not if the list is cleared and we start filling it again.

Comment: Fixed by extending `compareDispatcher`
`public static void compareDispatcher(List<Dispatch> l , Dispatch d){

        if (l.size() == 0){
            l.add(d);
        }
        else {
            for (Dispatch item : l) {
                if (item.compareTo(d) == 0)
                    item.setWeight(item.getWeight() + d.getWeight());
                else
                    l.add(d);
            }
        }
        }`